# Setting web.config for deployment - .Net

Tags: c#, deployment, entity-framework-4, azure, web-config

The following is my web.config file. I am currently learning how to deploy a website on my own since I found no sources whatsoever to learn how to deploy a website using ADO.NET (entity framework/ use of a DB model) which connects to an azure database. I created a test page which simply gets all records from a specific table. Works perfect in development. I simply uploaded web.config, default.aspx, default.aspx.cs and the bin folder. I am using go daddy. Unfortunately I get an error telling me that I am not connecting to the database! Can anyone help me??!!!

The following is my error and stack trace
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5061898
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +341
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +52

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +161
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +98
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetIListSourceListInternal() +13
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList() +10
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(Object dataSource, String dataMember) +54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ReadOnlyDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String viewName) +41
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView() +266
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.GetData() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   WebApplication1._default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\...\WebApplication1\default.aspx.cs:15
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

The following is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&amp;quot&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The connection string is not correct. Try using its values in SQL Server Management Studio. Can you connect? (You won't).

Comment: It is the same connection string I use from my Visual Studio. I will try what you told me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoDaddy is probably blocking outbound connections.

Contact their support, or switch to a decent host.

Comment: Seems reasonable. What do you think I should ask them exactly to do for me? Simply to unblock such a connection? :)

Comment: Unblock the port used by SQL Server (1433, IIRC, but check)

Comment: wait, is this what I should tell them? or what I should do? because if its what I should do, I'm sorry I didn't understand you well!

Comment: That's what you should ask them.

Comment: this is what go daddy told me: Thank you for contacting Online Support.  Please be aware that you can only connect to other websites by ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). Other ports can not be used on hosting plans.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714154/unable-to-connect-from-third-party-hosted-web-application-to-sql-azure-database

Comment: @test: I thought so.  You should switch to a decent host, such as AppHarbor.  (They do databases too)

Comment: thank you very much! unfortunately I have already for hosting :( So does AppHarbor allow me to connect to azure?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried configuring the SQL Azure Firewall to allow connections from your GoDaddy server?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx

Comment: yes at the moment I am allowing all IPs from 0 0 0 0 to 255 255 255 255!

Comment: the port number from go daddy seems to be a problem :( this is what go daddy told me: Thank you for contacting Online Support. Please be aware that you can only connect to other websites by ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). Other ports can not be used on hosting plans.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714154/unable-to-connect-from-third-party-hosted-web-application-to-sql-azure-database

Comment: Would it be an option to host a WCF service in a Windows Azure Web Role that connects to SQL Azure and have your website connect to that WCF service? (I know it adds an extra cost, but it will work)

Comment: so I need to buy a subsrcription to have a hosted service? Wouldnt it be more easy to deploy my app to windows azure or is it more expensive? Can you provide me with a tutorial of what you said since I m quite a beginner at everything? Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look here to calculate your cost http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ and take a look here for introductory tutorials: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/